# best data type for hh:mm in a Hive Table

Tags: hive, data-warehouse

What is the appropriate Hive data type to store "hh:mm" into a Hive table? I've been using VARCHAR(5) however I've seen that that SMALLINT is used as well, this use case will be for a data warehouse where users will be able to filter data by this field. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE air_time > '10:00' and air_time < '14:00'
```

For example, in sql server there is a [TIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) data type that was very convenient.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd consider storing hours and minutes as separate integral columns. Might be cleaner and more convenient, unless you have to do some sort of time/interval arithmetic on this field. Also, whats the underlying data format?

Comment: the underlying format is varchar, one of the use cases for hh:mm is to be able to differentiate schedules of a radio show, so analytical users might need to filter data measurements by their schedule, for example the 12:00 show or shows that are between 12:00 and 15:00, as there are many shows in many networks. I think your suggestion is definitely a good one however I'm still hesitant on the usability, in sql server there is  a TIME data type which made this very convenient, I guess I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: For example `select '12:00' between '12:00' and '15:00';` will return `true`. What the problem with string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varchar(5) is the most suitable data type. Looks like you don't need to do arithmetic on this data. Storing it in hh:mm varchar format allows you to do the comparison.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is what answers the question, we can edit this answer if that changes in the future or better answers are added, varchar(5) meets all my needs in terms of filtering and even reporting.